# Excel VBA Delimiting issues and Time Conversion

Tags: vba, excel

so i got an issue on a worksheet, very easy, very simple, just something i haven't worked with before. I've done some research, however I am not able to get my code right, and I think I've hit that wall were I just keep trying the same thing, in a different way.

Anyhow. We import a timesheet from a website, it gets saved as into excel. the 'B' Column has all of the times we need to copy over to a different sheet. (I have that part of the code taken care of).The times are displayed as such:

```
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  
30m  
15m  
1h 30m  
1h  
15m  
30m  
30m  
15m  
1h  
1h 30m  
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

First issue is the program we use doesnt 1) like the h/m characters, and 2) doesnt like the 15/30/45 format (it likes the .25, .5 .75, decimal representation).

So I tried delimiting first and while it was somewhat successful at the minutes part, when dealing with the hours part, it just blew everything out past the 'h', I.E my 1h 30m became just 1.

What I need assistance with is how to go through these rows on the B column, split then recombine the info in the format we need, so the this would look like
Old       Need this format
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    30m  ----->  .5
    15m  ----->  .25
    1h 30m  --> 1.5
    1h  ------> 1.0
    15m   ---->  .25
    30m   ---->  .5
    30m   ---->  .5
    15m   ---->  .25
    1h  ------> 1.0
    1h 30m  --> 1.5
    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I have most of the other stuff I need in place, just delimiting is something I haven't messed with, and I do not have any good simple examples to go by to help learn.

Thank you in advanced. This forum is wonderful and full of awesome and knowledgeable people, and has greatly helped me and my coding abilities.

Comment: and vba is a must? as a formula will do the conversion easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will split the input at the space, and then calculate either the value (if followed by a "h") or the value / 60 (if followed by a "m"):

```
Function HoursAndMins(inValue As String) As Double
    Dim str
    Dim part
    Dim result As Double
    str = Split(inValue, " ")
    For Each part In str
        Select Case LCase(Right(part, 1))
            Case "h"
                result = result + CDbl(Left(part, Len(part) - 1))
            Case "m"
                result = result + CDbl(Left(part, Len(part) - 1)) / 60
        End Select
    Next
    HoursAndMins = result
End Function
```

It can be called from VBA as, for example:

```
Dim answer As Double
answer = HoursAndMins("1h 30m")
```

or as:

```
Dim answer As Double
answer = HoursAndMins(Range("B1").Value)
```

or it can be used in Excel as

```
=HoursAndMins(B1)
```

(assuming cell B1 contained something like `1h 30m`)

*Note: If you **are** wanting to use it as an Excel formula, Scott will give you a better formula so that you don't need to use this as a UDF.*

Answer (score 1):

This takes the value is Column B and puts their decimal equivalent in column C on the same page.

```
Sub convert()
Dim outarr As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim splt() As String
With Worksheets("Sheet15") ' change to your sheet
    arr = .Range("B1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Value
    ReDim outarr(1 To UBound(arr), 1 To 1)
    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        arr(i, 1) = Replace(arr(i, 1), "m", "")
        arr(i, 1) = Replace(arr(i, 1), "h", "|")
        arr(i, 1) = Replace(arr(i, 1), " ", "")
        splt = Split(arr(i, 1), "|")
        If UBound(splt) > 0 Then
            outarr(i, 1) = CDbl(splt(0)) + CDbl(IIf(splt(1) = "", 0, splt(1))) / 60
        Else
            outarr(i, 1) = CDbl(splt(0)) / 60
        End If
    Next i
    .Range("C1").Resize(UBound(arr), 1).Value = outarr
End With
End Sub
```

a formula that does what is wanted without vba:

```
=IFERROR(--TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("h" & B1,"h",REPT(" ",999),LEN("h" & B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("h" & B1,"h",""))),"m",""),999),"h","")),0)+ IFERROR(--TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("h" & B1,"h",REPT(" ",999),LEN("h" & B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE("h" & B1,"h",""))),"m",""),999))/60,0)
```

column C is the output from the vba and Column D the output from the formula:

[image]